# EntityFrameworkCore Linq error: variable 'country.Country' of type 'Country' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: linq, where-clause, invalidoperationexception

EntityFrameworkCore: 1.1.0

I always get an InvalidOperationException with a "simple" linq query and cannot figure out why. It works very well for the tags, but not for the countries.

I try to execute the following query:

```
var tags = new string[]{"guid1", "guid2"};
var countries = new int[]{1, 2};
var test = _dbContext.Articles
            .Include(a => a.Countries).ThenInclude(c => c.Country)
            .Include(a => a.Tags)
            .Where(article => article.Tags.Any(t => tags.Contains(t.Tag.Id)) &&
                              article.Countries.Any(c2 => countries.Contains(c2.Country.Id)))
           .ToList();
```

And always get the following exception:

**variable 'c2.Country' of type 'Country' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined**

With the following entities:

```
public class Article
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique ID of the article
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Article type
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public ArticleTypes Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the article tags.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The article tags.
    /// </value>
    public ICollection<ArticleTag> Tags { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the countries.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The countries.
    /// </value>
    public ICollection<ArticleCountry> Countries { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleCountry
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The identifier.
    /// </value>
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the country.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The country.
    /// </value>
    public Country Country { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public int Position { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The identifier.
    /// </value>
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unique country code
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Country name
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tag unique key
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tag name
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleTag
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the order.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The order.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    public int Position { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the tag.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The tag.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

I can also see the following warning in the console:

*warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[8]
      The LINQ expression '{__countries_1 => Contains(Convert((?[c2.Country].Id?)))}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. To configure this warning use the DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API (event id 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning'). ConfigureWarnings can be used when overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or using AddDbContext on the application service provider.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding [Required] in ArticleCountry.Country property

```
public class ArticleCountry
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Gets or sets the identifier.
   /// </summary>
   /// <value>
   /// The identifier.
   /// </value>
   [Required]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets or sets the country.
   /// </summary>
   /// <value>
   /// The country.
   /// </value>
   [Required]
   public Country Country { get; set; }

   /// <summary>
   /// 
   /// </summary>
   public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

Seems like the join didn't like nullable FK